# Shortcode is not working in homepage page template (custom front page)

Tags: plugins, shortcode

The shortcode for the MailChimp subscribe form in my theme's custom homepage is not working. But when I put the same shortcode in a blog page and other pages, then it is working

I put the shortcode `[mc4wp_form id="id"]` in theme pages and it's working.

But when I put `<?php echo do_shortcode ([mc4wp_form id="id"]); ?>` in my custom homepage, then it's not working.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The common way to approach this is to use `do_shortcode()`.  But that's not an efficient way to do it because it has to run a pretty extensive regex (regular expression) to parse through every single shortcode in your WP install to get to the one you are asking for.  [See this post for a more thorough explanation](https://konstantin.blog/2013/dont-do_shortcode/).

A better approach is to run the callback function needed directly.  But that can sometimes be a challenge - either you have to dig through a lot of code to find it, or it may possibly be in an object class and how do you call that?

[J.D. Grimes has provided a good utility function](https://codesymphony.co/dont-do_shortcode/) for calling shortcodes this way so that you can get to the direct callback function without having to use do_shortcode().  Add the following function, which you can use for any shortcode instance:

```
/**
 * Call a shortcode function by tag name.
 *
 * @author J.D. Grimes
 * @link https://codesymphony.co/dont-do_shortcode/
 *
 * @param string $tag     The shortcode whose function to call.
 * @param array  $atts    The attributes to pass to the shortcode function. Optional.
 * @param array  $content The shortcode's content. Default is null (none).
 *
 * @return string|bool False on failure, the result of the shortcode on success.
 */
function do_shortcode_func( $tag, array $atts = array(), $content = null ) {
 
    global $shortcode_tags;
 
    if ( ! isset( $shortcode_tags[ $tag ] ) )
        return false;
 
    return call_user_func( $shortcode_tags[ $tag ], $atts, $content, $tag );
}
```

Then you can call your shortcode this way:

```
echo do_shortcode_func( 'mc4wp_form', array( 'id' => 'id' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotes around the shortcode in the `do_shortcode()` function:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[mc4wp_form id="id"]' ); ?>
```

`do_shortcode()` is a PHP [function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) that takes a [String](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) as an [argument](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php). The quotes are required to make the text a string.

Comment: still not working

Comment: What is this "custom front page" you're referring to? A page template? Is it in you theme folder?

Comment: yes it is in theme folder and has name tpl-home.php

Comment: I'm using wp-generic theme